# The IOS application cannot be open in Simulator 11

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have created single view app from template in Xcode and when I try to run this app in simulator the following error displayed. I have not made any changes in code at all. Xcode 11, deployment target IOS 13, no matter which IOS device.

````
Details

The request to open "my.app" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Unexpected error type.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = InvalidResponse;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain error 3.)
Domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain
Code: 3
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = OperationFailed;
}
--```
````

Comment: Are you running macOS inside a VM?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.6